# phone field validation for starting with + followed by country code and phone number

Tags: visual-workflow, validation, regular-expressions

I am trying to implement the phone validation for lightning flow screen.
Here is what i tried and it's working in https://regex101.com/, But when am trying to save in lightning  flow screen input field, it's saying syntax error. Can someone help on it.

`^(\+)\w{8,10}$`
Need format of +123456789,  +12345678, +1234567890.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backslashes are escape characters, so to get them into the regex, you need to double-up on them:

```
^(\\+)\\w{8,10}$
```

You also probably meant to restrict to *just* digits:

```
^(\\+)\\d{8,10}$
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, This worked.